# Studies of how people learn to solve puzzles

Tags: cognitive-psychology, learning, reference-request, experimental-psychology

I would like to build a cognitive model that is able to learn how to solve a complex puzzle such as the tower of Hanoi based off of limited feed-back (set of valid moves, closer to goal, farther from goal). I have found some references for learning the Tower of Hanoi and the performance of schizophrenics, but I was wondering if there was a particular name for the type of learning I'm looking for (advanced reinforcement learning?) and if there are further studies on how people learn these types of puzzles.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but the big umbrella term in the literature for puzzles like the Tower of Hanoi is `problem solving`.

A Google Scholar search for "tower of hanoi" and "problem solving" generates [~5000 hits](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22tower+of+hanoi%22+%22problem+solving%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C15&as_vis=1). Another related puzzle is the Tower of London, and that Scholar search generates an additional [~5000](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22tower+of+london%22+%22problem+solving%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C15&as_vis=1).

Comment: I'll add more details later today, but I'm kind of looking for a term and studies that focus on going from exploratory searching of a problem, to combining chains of moves or strategies (chunking? procedural learning? hierarchical reinforcement learning? instruction based learning?) when one becomes efficient at the problem